# What limits are imposed for mysql user creation?

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL 5.1.x

What is the cost of an account on disk when it is created in MySql? Also, what is the max number of accounts you can create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`What is the cost of an account on disk when it is created in MySql?`
Practically nothing (a few K to create the rows in the Grant tables).

`what is the max number of accounts you can create?`
Practically unlimited (the Grant tables can't exceed the maximum number of rows in a table, for which there is no upper limit in modern InnoDB tables, but for obscenely large numbers of rows you may have performance problems.  The chance of you having that many users / GRANTs is so small as to be a non-factor in capacity planning).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL accounts are stored in the `user` table of the `mysql` database. You are only limited by the amount of drive space you have. The disk cost is equal to the size of the row.